# Error em script Python para copiar arquivos .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, script

Fiz o seguinte script para estudar. O objetivo é copiar todos os arquivos com a extensão '.txt' da pasta 'teste1' para a pasta 'teste2'.

```
import shutil
import os

#Para garantir que o path é o caminho absoluto
e = os.path.abspath("/home/charanko/Desktop/teste1")
f = os.path.abspath("/home/charanko/Desktop/teste2")

#Para confirmar que o path é um caminho absoluto
print(os.path.isabs(e))
print(os.path.isabs(f))

source = os.listdir(e)
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.copy(files,f)
```

O seguinte erro é obtido:

```
True
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/charanko/Desktop/selectiveCopy.py", line 15, in <module>
    shutil.copy(files,f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 245, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fil.txt'
```

Esse erro: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fil.txt'` vi o pessoal em outros tópicos falando que era algo relacionado ao caminho absoluto. Pensei que tinha entendido, mas não. 
Os demais erros não consegui entender o que é.

Comment: esta parecendo que falta uma letra no nome, ñ seria file.txt ao invez de fil.txt?

Comment: @EltonNunes, não, o nome do arquivo de texto eu realmente deixei 'fil.txt'

Comment: realmente ñ faço ideia, oq eu faria nessa hora era ir printando o os.listdir pasta a pasta, ate chegar no arquivo e comparar com o caminho passado pelo os.path.abspath, não é a forma mais otimizada, mas grande chance de saber onde estar o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você não está especificando o caminho do arquivo na hora de copiar. 
O `shutil` está tentando acessar o arquivo `fil.txt` no diretório atual, o qual não existe. Você pode resolver isso especificando o diretório, dessa forma:

```
source = os.listdir(e)
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(e, files), f)
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, deu certo.